# Dates with lapply and sapply

Tags: r

I have imported a CSV file with numerous dates and have use the as.Date function to convert the date.  However, when I use the the mapply function to find the earlier of two dates, I either end up with a list with dates or a numeric vector.  How can I get a vector with dates?

```
POP.Start.final <- mapply(min, combinedOM$Cons.Start.Date.y, 
                               combinedOM$OS.Start.Date.y, 
                                MoreArgs = list(na.rm=T),SIMPLIFY=T)
```

This returns a numeric vector, changing to SIMPLIFY=F returns a list of dates, but I want a vector of dates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this specific case, I believe `pmin` does the trick:

```
POP.Start.final <- pmin(combinedOM$Cons.Start.Date.y,
  combinedOM$OS.Start.Date.y,
  na.rm=TRUE)
```

In the general case, `SIMPLIFY=TRUE` (the default) uses the utility function `simplify2array` to convert lists to vectors of atomic mode via `as.vector`. Because dates are internally stored as numeric, `SIMPLIFY=TRUE` will convert the list of dates to a vector of mode numeric and remove the `Date` class. You can set `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` to keep the `Date` class and then use `do.call` with `c` to convert the list to a vector.

```
POP.Start.final <- do.call(c,mapply(min, combinedOM$Cons.Start.Date.y, 
                               combinedOM$OS.Start.Date.y, 
                                MoreArgs = list(na.rm=TRUE),SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
```

Some reproducible code:

```
a <- as.Date(c("2012-01-11","2012-06-30","2012-04-18"))
b <- as.Date(c("2013-04-21","2012-03-22","2012-05-01"))
pmin(a,b)
#[1] "2012-01-11" "2012-03-22" "2012-04-18"
do.call(c,mapply(min,a,b,MoreArgs=list(na.rm=TRUE),SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
#[1] "2012-01-11" "2012-03-22" "2012-04-18"
```

As an aside, using `T` and `F` for `TRUE` and `FALSE` is slightly worrying because `T` and `F` can be reassigned while `TRUE` and `FALSE` cannot be reassigned.

Comment: Ooops. Your answer was first, but it looked more complex than needed. I will delete mine in a bit.

Comment: No worries. I'm trying to cover the bases when a nifty base function is not available, so our answers can be complementary.

Comment: Your explanation of why dates are converted to numbers is slightly off. `SIMPLIFY=TRUE` calls `simplify2array`, which converts its argument to a vector or matrix, and `is.vector(Sys.Date())` is `FALSE`. It doesn't have anything to do with the "most simple type".

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Edited. Does this make more sense?

Comment: @BlueMagister: yes; it's the same problem with not being able to use Dates in a for loop: Dates are not strictly vectors.

Comment: @BlueMagister: Thank you for the help!  I also tried a different approach - I added the numeric vector to my dataframe using cbind, and then used the following to convert the column from numeric to date: `combinedOM[,c("POP.Start.final")] <- as.Date(combinedOM[,c("POP.Start.final")])`

Comment: @BlueMagister: also note that `POP.Start.final <- pmin(combinedOM$Cons.Start.Date.y, combinedOM$OS.Start.Date.y, na.rm=TRUE)` sets POP.Start.final to a date vector, but `POP.Start.final <- unlist(mapply(min, combinedOM$Cons.Start.Date.y, combinedOM$OS.Start.Date.y, MoreArgs=list(na.rm=TRUE),SIMPLIFY=FALSE)` sets POP.Start.final to a numeric vector.

Comment: @LukasH Oops, you're right. `unlist` strips the `Date` class and leaves only the atomic `numeric`. I've used a different function to convert the list to a vector and keep the `Date` class`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best way, but the `origin` of the `as.Date` function is `January 1, 1970` or `1970-01-01` in the default date format.

So (with made up data replacing yours), this will work:

```
> one <- as.Date("2012-01-01")
> two <- as.Date("2012-03-13")
> 
> POP.Start.final <- as.Date(
                             mapply(min,
                                    one,
                                    two,
                                    MoreArgs=list(na.rm=T)
                                   ),
                                    origin="1970-01-01"
                            )
> str(POP.Start.final)
 Date[1:1], format: "2012-01-01"
```