# Apply and lubridate

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a problem with dates convertion. If I use ymd in apply, it returns a numeric, or if I use only ymd it's works.
Someone would have any idea ?

```
library(lubridate)
a <- data.frame(dates1=c("2011-01-01",'2011-02-01','2011-03-01'),
            dates2=c("2013-01-01",'2013-02-01','2013-03-01'))
apply(a, 2, FUN = function(x) ymd(x))

     dates1     dates2
[1,] 1293840000 1356998400
[2,] 1296518400 1359676800
[3,] 1298937600 1362096000

ymd(a$dates1)

[1] "2011-01-01 UTC" "2011-02-01 UTC" "2011-03-01 UTC"

ymd(a$dates2)

[1] "2013-01-01 UTC" "2013-02-01 UTC" "2013-03-01 UTC"
```

Comment: Use `lapply()`, as `apply()` drops the Date class to numeric.  You should really only use `apply()` with matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lapply()`:

```
lapply(a, function(x) ymd(x))
```

**Update/Explaination**

The `apply()` documentation states:

> In all cases the result is coerced by as.vector to one of the basic vector types before the dimensions are set, so that (for example) factor results will be coerced to a character array.

As J.Ulrich states in the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14449306/3691003) "dates aren't strictly vectors". `lapply()` is very similar to `apply()`, however it will return a list rather than a vector. Hence its ability to handle dates.

Answer (score 3):

`apply` tries to simplify it, using `as.matrix` if input **X** is two-dimensional, see this example:

```
as.matrix(ymd("2013-01-01"))
      [,1]
[1,] 15706
```

`?apply`

> **Details**
>   If X is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null dim
>   value (such as a data frame), apply attempts to coerce it to an array
>   via as.matrix if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame) or via
>   as.array.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `mutate_each`

```
library(dplyr)
a %>%
    mutate_each(funs(ymd))
#     dates1     dates2
#1 2011-01-01 2013-01-01
#2 2011-02-01 2013-02-01
#3 2011-03-01 2013-03-01
```