# best practices for avoiding roundoff gotchas in date manipulation

Tags: r, date, datetime, lubridate

I am doing some date/time manipulation and experiencing explicable, but unpleasant, round-tripping problems when converting date -> time -> date . I have temporarily overcome this problem by rounding at appropriate points, but I wonder if there are best practices for date handling that would be cleaner. I'm using a mix of base-R and `lubridate` functions.

**tl;dr** is there a good, simple way to convert from decimal date (YYYY.fff) to the `Date` class (and back) without going through POSIXt and incurring round-off (and potentially time-zone) complications??

Start with a few days from 1918, as separate year/month/day columns (not a critical part of my problem, but it's where my pipeline happens to start):

```
library(lubridate)
dd <- data.frame(year=1918,month=9,day=1:12)
```

Convert year/month/day -> date -> time:

```
dd <- transform(dd,
                time=decimal_date(make_date(year, month, day)))
```

The successive differences in the resulting time vector **are not exactly 1 because of roundoff**: this is understandable but leads to problems down the road.

```
table(diff(dd$time)*365)
## 0.999999999985448  1.00000000006844 
##                 9                 2
```

Now suppose I convert back to a date: the dates are slightly before or after midnight (off by <1 second in either direction):

```
d2 <- lubridate::date_decimal(dd$time)
#  [1] "1918-09-01 00:00:00 UTC" "1918-09-02 00:00:00 UTC"
#  [3] "1918-09-03 00:00:00 UTC" "1918-09-03 23:59:59 UTC"
#  [5] "1918-09-04 23:59:59 UTC" "1918-09-05 23:59:59 UTC"
#  [7] "1918-09-07 00:00:00 UTC" "1918-09-08 00:00:00 UTC"
#  [9] "1918-09-09 00:00:00 UTC" "1918-09-09 23:59:59 UTC"
# [11] "1918-09-10 23:59:59 UTC" "1918-09-12 00:00:00 UTC"
```

If I now want dates (rather than POSIXct objects) I can use `as.Date()`, but to my dismay **as.Date() truncates rather than rounding** ...

```
tt <- as.Date(d2)
## [1] "1918-09-01" "1918-09-02" "1918-09-03" "1918-09-03" "1918-09-04"
## [6] "1918-09-05" "1918-09-07" "1918-09-08" "1918-09-09" "1918-09-09"
##[11] "1918-09-10" "1918-09-12"
```

So the differences are now 0/1/2 days:

```
table(diff(tt))
# 0 1 2 
# 2 7 2
```

I can fix this by rounding first:

```
table(diff(as.Date(round(d2))))
## 1 
## 11
```

but I wonder if there is a better way (e.g. keeping POSIXct out of my pipeline and staying with dates ...

As suggested by [this R-help desk article from 2004](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf) by Grothendieck and Petzoldt:

> When considering which class to use, always
>   choose the least complex class that will support the
>   application. That is, use `Date` if possible, otherwise use
>   `chron` and otherwise use the `POSIX` classes. Such a strategy will greatly reduce the potential for error and increase the reliability of your application.

The extensive table in this article shows how to translate among `Date`, `chron`, and `POSIXct`, but doesn't include decimal time as one of the candidates ...

Comment: `round_date` may be another option which is only slightly different than what you are currently doing: `d2 = round_date(date_decimal(dd$time), "days"); as.Date(d2)`

Comment: FWIW `round_date` does seem like a reasonable path, but it is worth noting that it returns as POSIXct.

Comment: At one point in my pipeline I have the values as decimal dates. The ultimately answer could well be "try harder to preserve the date info in your pipeline", but the proximal question is "how to robustly back-convert decimal dates back into dates"?

Comment: @BenBolker where does `POSIXct` discussion come in here? why not just define `date_decimal2 = function(decimal, tz = NULL) round(date_decimal(decimal, tz))`?

Comment: @BenBolker, one needs to assume a time when converting from `Date` to decimal date. If we are concerned only with date, we could assume that time is middle of the day `12:00:00` instead of `00:00:00` and there would be no issue: `dd$time = with(dd, decimal_date(ymd_hms(paste(year, month, day, "12:00:00"))))`

Comment: Guess the best practice here is to entirely avoid decimal dates, especially if you are not interested in time details. You should work on your pipeline.

Comment: Pedantically, `ymd_hms()` takes the data through a POSIXct step, but truth be told I like that answer best of all @d.b.

Comment: Me too. @d.b.: can you post that comment as an answer? (Unfortunately you can't award the bounty to yourself, can you ... ?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like it would be best to avoid converting back from decimal time if at all possible.

When converting from date to decimal date, one also needs to account for time. Since `Date` does not have a specific time associated with it, `decimal_date` inherently assumes it to be `00:00:00`.

However, if we are concerned only with the date (and not the time), we could assume the time to be anything. Arguably, middle of the day (`12:00:00`) is as good as the beginning of the day (`00:00:00`). This would make the conversion back to `Date` more reliable as we are not at the midnight mark and a few seconds off does not affect the output. One of the ways to do this would be to add `12*60*60/(365*24*60*60)` to `dd$time`

> ```
> dd$time2 = dd$time + 12*60*60/(365*24*60*60)
> data.frame(dd[1:3],
>            "00:00:00" = as.Date(date_decimal(dd$time)),
>            "12:00:00" = as.Date(date_decimal(dd$time2)),
>            check.names = FALSE)
> #   year month day        00:00:00        12:00:00
> #1  1918     9   1      1918-09-01      1918-09-01
> #2  1918     9   2      1918-09-02      1918-09-02
> #3  1918     9   3      1918-09-03      1918-09-03
> #4  1918     9   4      1918-09-03      1918-09-04
> #5  1918     9   5      1918-09-04      1918-09-05
> #6  1918     9   6      1918-09-05      1918-09-06
> #7  1918     9   7      1918-09-07      1918-09-07
> #8  1918     9   8      1918-09-08      1918-09-08
> #9  1918     9   9      1918-09-09      1918-09-09
> #10 1918     9  10      1918-09-09      1918-09-10
> #11 1918     9  11      1918-09-10      1918-09-11
> #12 1918     9  12      1918-09-12      1918-09-12
> ```
>
> **It should be noted, however, that the value of decimal time obtained in this way will be different.**

Answer (score 3):

`lubridate::decimal_date()` is returning a `numeric`. If I understand you correctly, the question is how to convert that `numeric` into `Date` and have it round appropriately without bouncing through `POSIXct`.

`as.Date(1L, origin = '1970-01-01')` shows us that we can provide `as.Date` with days since some specified origin and convert immediately to the Date type.  Knowing this, we can skip the year part entirely and set it as origin. Then we can convert our decimal dates to days:

`as.Date((dd$time-trunc(dd$time)) * 365, origin = "1918-01-01")`.

So, a function like this might do the trick (at least for years without leap days):

```
date_decimal2 <- function(decimal_date) {
  years <- trunc(decimal_date)
  origins <- paste0(years, "-01-01")
  # c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449166/dates-with-lapply-and-sapply
  do.call(c, mapply(as.Date.numeric, x = (decimal_date-years) * 365, origin = origins, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
}
```

Side note: I admit I went down a bit of a rabbit hole with trying to move origin around deal with the pre-1970 date.  I found that the further origin shifted from the target date, the more weird the results got (and not in ways that seemed to be easily explained by leap days).  Since origin is flexible, I decided to target it right on top of the target values.  For leap days, seconds, and whatever other weirdness time has in store for us, on your own head be it. =)